# Inequality for a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Let $\xi > 0$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb E[\exp{(-\xi)}]=\exp{(-a)}$. How to show that for any $c>0$
$$P(\xi \ge c) \le \frac{1-\exp{(-a)}}{1-\exp{(-c)}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function $1 - \exp(-x)$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$ on $\Bbb R$ (its derivative is $\exp(-x)$, which is always positive), we have

$$P(\xi \ge c) = P[1 - \exp(-\xi)) \ge 1 - \exp(-c)].$$

By Markov's inequality,

$$P[1 - \exp(-\xi) \ge 1 - \exp(-c)] \le \frac{1}{1 - \exp(-c)}E[1 - \exp(-\xi)].$$

Use the assumption $E[\exp(-\xi)] = \exp(-a)$ to finish the argument.

Comment: does not Chebyshev's inequality have variance in it?

Comment: That's not the only one, but I should have been clearer. The inequality I speak of is $P(X \ge a) \le E(X)/a$.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a reference to Chebyshev's inequality in this form. Could you pleas provide a link?

Comment: The common term in probability is *Markov's inequality*. See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) for the statement and proofs. In general measure theory one uses the term "Chebyshev's inequality" instead of "Markov's inequality".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since $\xi>0,\ c>0$,
$$
1=e^{-\xi}+1-e^{-\xi}\geqslant e^{-\xi} + {\bf 1}_{\xi\geqslant c}(1-e^{-c})\,.
$$